How can I auto resize the TWebComboBox's width to match the selected option's width in TMS WEB Core?
I've got a TWebComboBox component on my form and every item in it has a different text size.
Currently what I've done as a temporary solution is to just manually check the selected item's text content and then manually set the Width for the TWebComboBox:
procedure TForm_Leaderboards.cbGameChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  cb: TWebComboBox;
begin
  cb := TWebComboBox(Sender);

  if (cb.Text = 'Portal') then cb.Width := 95;
  if (cb.Text = 'Portal 2') then cb.Width := 105;
  if (cb.Text = 'Portal Stories: Mel') then cb.Width := 200;

  // ... Lots more If Statements for other Texts
end;

This works, but it's tedious to do this and obviously super hardcoded.
How can I make this dynamic so that the Width is automatically set to match the required width for the selected item's text?

I managed to get it working, but it's a bit hacky:
procedure TForm_Leaderboards.cbGameChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  cb, TempCB: TWebComboBox;
begin
  cb := TWebComboBox(Sender);

  TempCB := TWebComboBox.Create(nil);
  try
    TempCB.WidthStyle := ssAuto;
    TempCB.Font := cb.Font;
    TempCB.Items.Text := cb.Text;
    TempCB.Parent := Self;

    cb.Width := TempCB.Width; // Sets correct width
  finally
    TempCB.Free;
  end;
end;

Explanation:
Turns out that if you set the WidthStyle to ssAuto, then the TWebComboBox will automatically resize itself to the Width of the longest item in Items.Text.
So we can abuse this by creating a new temporary TWebComboBox and have only one item in the Items.Text (The selected item), then the TWebComboBox will automatically resize itself to the Width for that one item, and then we can get that Width and apply it to the correct TWebComboBox.
